# Spring Boot Service Testing

Tags: spring, testing, junit, mocking, boot

I have a problem with testing my application.
I want to test this method:

```
public Optional<UserDto> getUser(String username) {
        Optional<User> userOptional = this.userRepository.findById(username);
        if (userOptional.isPresent()) {
            UserDto userDto = this.convert(userOptional.get());
            return Optional.of(userDto);
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }
```

I tried to test it, but the line coverage shows that inside the if statement is not checked.
The tests I wrote:

```
@Test
    void getUserShouldReturnAnOptionalOfUserDtoIfItIsFound() {
        Optional<UserDto> userDtoOptional = this.underTest.getUser(user.getUsername());
        Mockito.verify(userRepository).findById(user.getUsername());
        userDtoOptional.ifPresent(userDto -> 
                Assertions.assertThat(userDto).isInstanceOf(UserDto.class));
    }

@Test
    void getUserTestShouldReturnOptionalEmptyWhenUserIsNotFound() {
        String username = "johndoe";
        Optional<UserDto> userDtoOptional = this.underTest.getUser(username);
        Mockito.verify(userRepository).findById(username);
        userDtoOptional.ifPresent(userDto ->
                Assertions.assertThat(userDto).isInstanceOf(Optional.empty().getClass()));
    }
```

Thank you if you have an advice!

Comment: Where are the "stubbing"s  `Mockito.when(...)`?

Comment: I don't have any. Is it neccessary?

Comment: ..as least for the "found" case, yes! you should (something like): `when(userRepository.findById(eq(user.getUsername()))).thenReturn(Optional.of(someTestUser));` ..then you can also assert on (result) dto comparing to (expected) `someTestUser`

Comment: Thank you. I read the mockito documentation and you said it right.